# io.js "Uncaught Error: listen EADDRINUSE"

Tags: node.js, travis-ci

Node v0.10 and 0.12 pass just fine with the same code. Locally, all versions of Node/io pass. I'm using [portscanner](https://npmjs.com/portscanner) to find an available port in the range of 3000-3030. I keep getting this error for io.js only:

```
 Uncaught Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:3000
  at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:844:11)
  at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:867:20)
  at Server._listen2 (net.js:1194:14)
  at listen (net.js:1227:10)
  at net.js:1330:9
  at callMakeAsyncCbNT (dns.js:71:12)
```

Switching portscanner's range to 3001-3030 produces the same error, only with `3001` in it.

Could this be a problem on Travis' side? I'm not much of a server guy, to be honest.

Comment: have you try it on a VM where there is only io.js installed?

Comment: Isn't that what Travis does? It installs on each session.

Answer (score -1):

I swapped out [portscanner](https://npmjs.com/portscanner) and instead just listened to port 0 for starting my server:

```
var server = http.createServer(callback);

server.listen(0, "127.0.0.1", function() {
    console.log( server.address().port );
});
```

No more error when attempting to serve on a port that portscanner claimed was available. It's "available" relied on ECONNREFUSED, which doesn't necessarily mean it's available.